# Quick sort partition algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

```
void partition(int *a, int size) {
   int pivot = a[0];
   int left = 0, right = 0;
   for(left = 1, right = size-1; left <= right; left++, right--) {
       if(a[left] >= pivot && a[right] <= pivot){
           swap(left, right, a);
       }
   }
   swap(0, right, a);
}
```

I wrote this method to partition an array as a preliminary step in order to apply quick sort, I tested it on this sample data:

```
8 2 5 13 4 19 12 6 3 11 10 7 9
```

the correct output should be:

```
6 2 5 7 4 3 8 12 19 11 10 13 9
```

but the actual output is:

```
6 2 5 13 4 3 8 12 19 11 10 7 9
```

The algorithm has to swap `13` with `7` but it fails due to the `&&` condition in the above loop. I want to increment `left` only if `a[left] >= pivot` and decrement `right` only if `a[right]<= pivot`.

Comment: just in case this is not some sort of learning exercises: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: @111111: Considering the question, `std::partition` would be the more appropriate reference.

Comment: @JerryCoffin very probably, I didn't really read the question in depth just I hoped you weren't reinventing the wheel in production.

Comment: @111111: I hope he wasn't too. I, however, am so old I was actually the original inventor of the wheel. :-)

Comment: @JerryCoffin you invented the quick sort partition algo?

Comment: @111111: no, he invented the wheel — it's a square (sometimes round) thingy found on wheelbarrows, bicycles, carts, and cars.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's still pretty impressive

Comment: I don't understand the question. If this is for your learning, and you've identified the problem, and the solution, where is the question? Is there something stumping you from implementing your fix?

Comment: Your code unconditionally increments left and decrements right, but your comments say you want to increment left conditionally and you want to decrement right conditionally.  So, if the comments are correct, you need to bring the code into line with the comments, don't you?

Comment: I hope this is homework: given the choice of the pvot, the degenerate case is sorted, or almost sorted input.  For the rest, the simplest (but not the most optimal) solution for doing the partitioning is the one used by Jon Bentley in his Programming Pearls book.  All of the others I've seen have more or less tricky edge conditions.

Comment: If it weren't homework he'd be using `sort()` from `<algorithm>` at the very least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You more or less answered your own question. You probably want to do something like this:

```
void partition(int *a, int size) {
    int pivot = a[0];
    int left, right;
    for(left = 1, right = size-1; left < right; )
    {
        if(a[left] > pivot && a[right] <= pivot)
        {
            swap(left, right, a);
        }
        if(a[left] <= pivot) left++;
        if(a[right] > pivot) right--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that using the first element as the partition pivot is a bad practice, since then quicksort decays to worst case on a sorted/almost sorted array - which is not as rare as we wanted it to be.

Answer (score 2):

here is another option, little bit more similar to the original one

```
int partition(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    int pivot = arr[left];
    while (left != right)
    {
        if (arr[left] > arr[right])
        {
            swap(arr[left], arr[right]);
        }
        if (pivot == arr[left])
            right--;
        else // Pivot == arr[right]
            left++;
    }
    return left;
}
```