# My quick sort implementation fails in some cases

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have implemented a quick sort algorithm but when I tested it I noticed that it fails when the input array has the largest element in the first element (this is the element I got the pivot from). Here's my code:

```
void partition(int *a,int size){
    if(size<=1){return;}
    int pivot=a[0];
    int left=0,right=0;
    for(left=1,right=size-1;left<=right;){    //was size-1
        if(a[left]>=pivot&&a[right]<=pivot) {
            swap(left,right,a);
        }

        if(a[left]<pivot){left++;}
        if(a[right]>pivot){right--;}
    }
    swap(0,right,a);
    partition(a,right-1);
    partition(&(a[right+1]),size-right-1);
}
```

Some samples that it fails on:

```
I/P 245  111  32    4
O/P 4   111  32  245     `

I/P 154   11   43  3  7
O/P   7   11   43  3  154
```

What are the possible mistakes I have made?

Comment: Closely related to previous question [Quick sort partition algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782209/quick-sort-partition-algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem lies here :

```
partition(a,right-1); // <- It's partition(array,size)!
```

Change it to

```
partition(a,right);
```

And it will work. I think you know the reason.
For the partition function to work correctly, you must supply 2 things :

1) The array to work on.
  2) The number of elements it has, the size.

The problem lies in the first recursive call to partition the left subarray:  `partition(a,right-1)`

The argument 2, the  `size`, is incorrectly specified to be `right-1`, when it is actually `right`.

This can be worked out by using the fact that the number of elements in an array from an index `a` to `b` ( both included,`b>=a`) are  `N= b-a+1`.

Here, we have `a=0`, `b=right-1`, thus the number of elements in the left sub array, the `size`, `N`=`(right-1)-(0)+1`=`right`.

Thus the  to work correctly, you must call it like `partition(a,right);`. 
The left sub array ends at `right-1`, but it has `right-1+1`=`right` elements.

Happens all the time :)

Comment: please could you give more explanation?

Comment: you mean that i have to pass right not right-1 because i begins from element No.1?

Comment: @Eslam Updated. Amit's point is worth noting as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a case where there is an element in the array which is the pivot, in the partition function.

Assume `arr = { 5, 5, 1 , 1, 5, }`

```
pivot = 5
iter1:
left=1, arr[left]=5 ; right=4,arr[right]=5
(swapping)
not increasing left nor decreasing right - since 5 < 5 == false ; 5 > 5 == false
```

Next iteration, the same scenario will repeat itself, and you will actually get an infinite loop.

One way to deal with it is to determine that the "big" part will also increase all elements that are exactly the pivot, and swap elements if `arr[right] < pivot` (not `<=`), and decrease `right` if `arr[right] >= pivot` (not `>`), something like:

```
...
for(left=1,right=size-1;left<=right;){    //was size-1      
        if(a[left]>=pivot&&a[right]<pivot) { 
        //                         ^ note < not <=
        swap(left,right,a);
    }

    if(a[left]<pivot){left++;}
    if(a[right]>=pivot){right--;}
    //        ^ note >=
}
...
```

Comment: ok, this is a great notice but this isn't the main cause of the problem mentioned above, any ways thanks