# What is the purpose of these lines of swap code in quicksort application?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to understand an implementation or an application of quicksort to find the kth smallest element
Here is the code that I am trying to understand

```
public int quicksort(int a[], int start, int end, int k) {
    if(start < end) {
        int pivot = partition(a, start, end);
        if(pivot == k -1) {
            return pivot;
        } else if(pivot > k - 1){
            return quicksort(a, start, pivot, k);
        } else {
            return quicksort(a, pivot + 1, end, k);
        }
    } else if(start == end) {
        return k==1?start:-1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
public int partition(int a[], int start, int end) {
    int pivot = start;
    int i = pivot + 1;
    int j = end;
    while(a[i] < a[pivot] && i < end) {
        i ++;
    } 
    while(a[j] > a[pivot] && j >= 0) {
        j --;
    } 
    if(i < j) {
        swap(a, start, end);
    }
    swap(a,j, pivot);
    return pivot;
}
private void swap(int a[], int swap1, int swap2) {
    int temp = a[swap1];
    a[swap1] = a[swap2];
    a[swap2] = temp;
}
```

I understand for trying to find the kth smallest element, you want to use quicksort because elements to the left of pivot will be less than the pivot and elements to the right of the pivot will be greater than. So that way if you're trying to find the 4th smallest element, and the pivot is at index 3, you can just return it because you know it is the 4th smallest since there are 3 elements smaller than it.

I am having trouble understanding the two swaps in the partition method.

At the conclusion of the first while loop, index i will be at a position at which all elements less than the pivot will be to the left of i. Index j will be at a position at which all elements greater than the pivot will be to the right of j.

What is the purpose of this swap code inside partition?
Can anyone give an example of why this of code is necessary? How will these ever meet?

```
if(i < j) {
        swap(a, i, j);
}
```

And also for this swap line(also inside partition), why did the author swap pivot and j, and not pivot and i? Is it arbitrary?

```
        swap(a,j, pivot);
```

Comment: Have you tested the code? It does not look correct to me. It just checks the first element that is >= pivot and the last element that is <= pivot. It stops after finding these two. It should cover the entire array.

Comment: What do you mean? It does check the rest of the array

Comment: Like you compare pivot with the kth element, if pivot is greater, than you check the section before, else ccheck the section after

Comment: The code looked incorrect to me too, so I tested it and indeed it doesn't work...

Comment: Just looking at the while condition `a[i] < a[pivot]` - it should be the opposite...

Comment: I think that's right because everything to the left of i should be less than pivot

Comment: Can you propose an edit to make the code work? I don't see any logic flaws in this

Comment: The purpose of the swaps is to *do the sorting.* Without swapping there is no sorting,

Comment: @EJP Apparently this code doesn't work. Can you propose an edit to fix these? I really don't see what this issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the partition algorithm present at : [Quick sort partition algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782209/quick-sort-partition-algorithm)

The algorithm you are using returns incorrect pivot